# How update TableView from JSON

Tags: ios, json, nsmutablearray, tableview

I have big problem with update my webdata from JSON. SO i have simple TableView with parse from JSON URL. When i pushed to  my button - infromation from JSON wrote to tableviewCell but i need that this information will be update any time. SO i have my code:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

        [super viewDidAppear:animated];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url.json"];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        if (connection) {
            webdata = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];

            [mytableview reloadData];

        }
```

i wrote this code but my information do not update, what i doing wrong? I tried also ViewDidAppear, viewWillAppear. but nothing.

Added cellForRow method.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(! cell)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
    }



    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Can you post your cellForRow method? You need to parse the json elements, store them in an Array, and base the tableView on this array as datasource.

Comment: You need to assign what ever you fetch from webservice to the dataSource of tableView in your case it seems to be an array. Show the real code where you assign the value to that array and then reload the tableView.

Comment: NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webdata options:0 error:nil];
    
    


    
       
    for (NSDictionary *person in json) {
        
        
        NSNumber *art = [person objectForKey:@"artist"];
        
        NSNumber *song2 = [person objectForKey:@"start"];
        
        [array addObject:art];
        
        [array2 addObject:song2];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with block based NSURLConnection. I guess the way you form webdata was the issue.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url.json"];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *urlResponse, NSData * webdata, NSError *reponseError) {

    NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: webdata
                                                    options:0
                                                      error:nil];
    for (NSDictionary *person in json) {
        //Are these numbers or strings
        NSString *art = person[@"artist"];
        NSString *song2 = person[@"start"];
        [array addObject:art];
        [array2 addObject:song2];
    }
    [mytableview reloadData];

}];
```

It is not recommended to keep two arrays for displaying just artist name and song name. The data is well formed. Save these data in array as such. In the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` when you need to show the data using the index fetch the person and find corresponding name and song name.

Answer (score 1):

Use  this    `-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection  NSURLConnection delgate method.`

```
  connection.delgate=self;
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
// write your parsing logic 
// reload your table here
[mytableview reloadData];

}
```

Comment: then write your logic  of viewDidAppear in button click method

Comment: And after when i will push button my table view will be reload with new information?

Comment: when you press your button then it create NSURLconnection instance and send request to server , after getting responce from server connectionDidFinishLoading is called . In connectionDidFinishLoading you write your parsing logic and reload table

Comment: Okey i will try this.. and after a write

Answer (score 0):

Bringing data from `JSON` is an asynchronous process. So you need to place a `NSNotification` in following the line when you are **placing objects to array**. And create a custom **function** in which `reload` your `table` and this **function** will be called by `NSNotificationCentre` when your `array has all the data from JSON`.

Let me know if you need any further help.

**EDIT:**

```
    -your JSON block{

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"newList" object:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadData) name:@"Doreload" object:nil];
}

-(void)reloadData               // Method to reload data and show data in table view
{
    [self.table reloadData];
}
```

Comment: I added NSNotification to ViewDidLoad, also i created VOID with reload table data but nothing...oh my god what i doing wrong?